# Use of JSON_EXTRACT() in a loop – Return Data from a JSON Document in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, jsonencode

I try to use the JSON_EXTRACT() function, on my request I have to loop on the "item" object (attention not "items" which is present several times in the JSON file) :

```
{
    "quantity": 1,
    "amount": 10,
    "token": "27a6a39167bd6287f0c84e1534df232990e28d2d",
    "items": [
        {
            "quantity": "1",
            "amount": 10,
            "ht_amount": 9.090909090909092,
            "tva_amount": 0.9090909090909092,
            "ttc_amount": 10,
            "item": {
                "id": 108828,
                "user_id": 38141,
                "title": "Teste Offer",
                "description": "<p>lorem ipsum<\/p>",
                "type_offer": "offer",
                "brand": null,
                "amount": 25,
                "type_shipping": [
                    "hand"
                ],
                "amount_shipping": null,
                "tag_categories": [
                    4
                ],
                "geo_lat": "0",
                "geo_long": "0",
                "open_time": null,
                "is_flash_offer": 0,
                "is_activate": 1,
                "is_offer_moderate": 0,
                "is_boost": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-01-29 14:42:23",
                "updated_at": "2020-01-29 14:42:24",
                "slug": "teste-offer-108828",
                "site_web": null,
                "facebook": null,
                "instagram": null,
                "discount_amount": 10,
                "discount_percentage": "",
                "benefits": "",
                "type_price": "price",
                "type_purchase": "purchase_camcha",
                "website_offer": "",
                "views": null,
                "clicks": null,
                "favoris": null,
                "is_default_free_offer": 0,
                "is_camcha_offer": 0,
                "address": "Etoug, Cameroun",
                "postal_code": "0000",
                "tva_offer": 10,
                "created_date_format": "29\/01\/2020 02:42:23",
                "real_categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "parent_id": 0,
                        "name": "Services",
                        "slug": "services",
                        "image": null,
                        "description": null,
                        "position": 7,
                        "is_product_show": 0,
                        "created_at": "2019-12-12 15:24:11",
                        "updated_at": "2019-12-12 15:24:11",
                        "is_activate": 1,
                        "image_url": ""
                    }
                ],
                "offer_images": [],
                "user": {
                    "id": 38141,
                    "parent": 0,
                    "first_name": "yannick",
                    "last_name": "Holly",
                    "email": "fogang24@gmail.com",
                    "phone": "0698452884",
                    "address": "Etoug, Cameroun",
                    "address_2": null,
                    "postal_code": "0000",
                    "country_id": 0,
                    "city": "Paris",
                    "birthday": null,
                    "profile_image": null,
                    "email_verified_at": "2019-12-27 08:05:08",
                    "token": "",
                    "stripe_id": "cus_GSDlGFUn1qWrDU",
                    "role": "pro",
                    "web": null,
                    "facebook": null,
                    "instagram": null,
                    "is_active": 1,
                    "is_suspend": 0,
                    "is_pending": 0,
                    "is_verify": 1,
                    "is_admin_validate": 1,
                    "is_user_complete": 0,
                    "is_payment_active": 0,
                    "accept_cgu": 1,
                    "accept_year": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:05:08",
                    "updated_at": "2019-12-30 08:25:58",
                    "payment_method_id": "pm_1FvJJdFfpClgVPUbz2wq9niK",
                    "slug": null,
                    "is_pro_advertiser": 0,
                    "url_profil_image": "",
                    "created_date_format": "27\/12\/2019 08:05:08",
                    "full_name": "Holly yannick",
                    "has_default_payment_method": false,
                    "user_company": {
                        "id": 53,
                        "user_id": 38141,
                        "company_status": null,
                        "siret": null,
                        "tva_number": null,
                        "code_naf": null,
                        "company_save_date": null,
                        "company_name": "",
                        "workplace": "",
                        "description": null,
                        "banniere": null,
                        "created_at": "2019-12-27 08:05:08",
                        "updated_at": "2019-12-27 08:05:08",
                        "slug": null,
                        "company_web": null,
                        "company_facebook": null,
                        "company_instagram": null,
                        "url_banniere": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This my request :

```
SELECT....
user_companies.company_postal_code AS code_postal,
orders.id AS commande,
json_extract(orders.basket,'$.items[0].item[0].tva_offer') AS tauxTVA,
...
```

I would like to know if it is possible to loop over the item attribute several times and retrieve the value as an indexed name, for example: rateVAT_1, rateVAT_2, ....

Thank you for your help.
Cédric.

I tried this doc, but it doesn't say anything about curls

https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: Your JSON value is partial. I do not see `tva_offer` property by specified path.

Comment: You're right. I update all the JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`"item"` is an object, not an array, so `[0]` is not valid for it.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.items[0].item.tva_offer')
```

| JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.items[0].item.tva_offer') |
| --- |
| 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uovKchOl)